# How to start Service in Broadcast Receiver?

Tags: android

I want to start Service in BroadcastReceiver, but this code makes error.

So.. what can I do for this??

```
BroadcastReceiver sn_english= new BroadcastReceiver() {
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        if(intent.getAction().equals("br1"))
        {

            //br1 EVENT

        }
        else if(intent.getAction().equals("br2"))
        {

            //start Service Here
            intent = new Intent(this, English_Service.class);
            startService(intent);

           //br2 EVENT

        }



    }
};
```

Comment: what is the problem you facing?

Comment: additional to the correct answers to use context instead of this, register the service in the manifest if You haven´t done it..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably following line causing issue:

```
 intent = new Intent(this, English_Service.class);
```

Because `this` means context of `onReceive` method

Use `context` instead of `this` as first parameter to `Intent` constructor :

```
intent = new Intent(context, English_Service.class);
context.startService(intent);
```

Answer (score 2):

You are missing `Context`..

change this two lines

```
intent = new Intent(this, English_Service.class);
startService(intent);
```

into

```
intent = new Intent(context, English_Service.class);
context.startService(intent);
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply use these lines

```
intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), English_Service.class);
getApplicationContext().startService(intent);
```